# PHP Tab implementation

Tags: php, javascript, css, tabs

I am trying to implement tabs within one tab and I would like some help with it.

I found some codes for the upper tab and tried to implement them into the lower set of tabs. ***These codes are not mine.*** I simply put them together to display what I wanted which obviously doesn't seem to work properly...

The following is what happens:

1) If you click on the upper tab, the page doesn't refresh itself.

2) If you click on the lower tab, the page refreshes itself and changes the "id=?" on the address bar which is what I **DO NOT** want.

Will it be possible for this problem to be fixed?

***This is a SAMPLE website so it will not be tidy***
http://www.swan10.nl/stuff/testie/testie.php

The CSS were made to display classes however the PHP website only works if these codes are used class="TabView" id="TabView". I know you cannot use "id" more than once so I even made another set of CSS & Javascript for id="Tabview2" etc but it didn't work so I didn't bother uploading them to save space.

I don't know if this is the best code to use but if they aren't please give some suggestions for better codes. Or I may have just missed something tiny and silly.

Please help & thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

I highly recommend you look at the Tabs feature of jQuery UI. It will seriously remove all the headaches of trying to figure out logic yourself, it's super easy to set up and use, and LOTS of people use it so there is plently of good information and support floating around on them.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/